# Execute SP2 given conditions inside SP1 - SQL Server

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to RUN SP2 inside SP1. The SP2 inserts several data into a table, one of those data is actual date.

So, i want that SP2 (inside SP1) only execute if in the column date, the date is within the last 10 days.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Question tagged as SQL-Server and down there solution for SQL-Server. It might be different for Oracle, which this question is about.

---

Yes it is.

Inside your SP1 you need to create `IF` statement and then `exec` your SP2.

Without more code form your side it is hard to write, but code in your SP1 should look something like:

```
IF (SELECT [YourDate] FROM [YourTable]) > DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
    EXEC SP1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I´m having an error compiling:                                                                                                                     
        create or replace PROCEDURE "SP_1" 

is


BEGIN

execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE E76';


IF(SELECT [RUN_DATE] FROM [TBL]) < DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE())
    execute SP_1();

Comment: Are you using MSSQL or Oracle? `Create or replace` is not valid for MSSQL - it's Oracles. And you are trying to run SP1 inside SP1.

Comment: its ORACLE.   create or replace PROCEDURE "SP_1" is BEGIN execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE E76'; IF(SELECT [RUN_DATE] FROM [TBL]) < DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()) execute SP_2();   The error is in the beginning of that SELECT .   ERROR:      Found "SELECT" symbol when was expected : ( - + case mod, etc.........

Comment: I don't know about Oracle. You tagged question as SQL-Server, not Oracle. Create a new question for this error and tag it properly.